# Automatic deployment of My_App on herokuapp failed

Tags: heroku

On **Notification**
"An automatic deployment for My_App failed. The build failed with the message Unauthorized.
Token from user xyz@gmail.com was used to interact with GitHub. This account was matched as the GitHub committer.
You can also check that the user who connected the app or pipeline to GitHub still has access to the app and to the Github repository.
In this case, reconnecting to GitHub will often fix the issue.
If you believe that this build failure was not due to an issue in your app, please open a support ticket."

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like you can no longer use GitHub for deployment due to the recent Heroku GitHub Hack. Here is their Security Notification POSTED 17 HOURS AGO, APR 21, 2022 23:53 UTC


While our customers remain unable to reconnect to GitHub via the Heroku dashboard, we wanted to share a supplement to the code deployment methods previously provided. For instructions on how to change your deployment method from GitHub to Heroku Git, please refer to the following Help article: How to switch deployment method from GitHub to Heroku Git with all the changes/app code available in a GitHub repo.